# The left regular representation of the Jacobi groups over local fields of characteristic >2 is type I?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, algebraic-groups, local-fields

Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field of characteristic $>2$. Consider the Jacobi group $G=H_{2n+1}(K)\rtimes Sp_{2n}(K)$, which is the semidirect product of the Heisenberg group $H_{2n+1}(K)$ with the symplectic group $Sp_{2n}(K)$.

Q: Is the left regular representation of $G$ type I?

It is well-known that if a locally compact separable group $G$ contains a closed cocompact type I subgroup H, then the left regular representation of $G$ is type I. This fact implies that if $G$ is a linear algebraic group over a non-archimedean local field $K$ of characteristic ZERO then the left regular representation of $G = G(K)$ is type I. (see "The left regular representation of a p-adic algebraic group is type I" by Gootman, Elliot C.; Kallman, Robert R.) 
In fact, I would like to verify the reduced group C*-algebra of the Jacobi group satisfies the Kunneth formula in the sense of Schochet. We can for instance prove that it belongs to the bootstrap class, which contains all type I $C^*$-algebras.

By the way, does anyone know a reference for the fact that the Heisenberg group $H_{2n+1}(K)$ is CCR(=liminal)? In geneal, CCR is stronger than type I (=postliminal=GCR) Note that we talk about local field of positive characteristic and this fact should follow
from the classical Mackey analysis in the same way as it follows for the real Heisenberg groups.

Comment: I added the OA tag since some of these groups might be known to people with OA interests (and since Type I is an OA concept anyway)

Comment: Liminality of $H_3(K)$ ($K$ non-archimedean) follows from the explicit description of the unitary irrep's, as given e.g. in section 1.2 of V. Lafforgue's paper:
http://vlafforg.perso.math.cnrs.fr/haagerup-rem.pdf
I expect the proof to be essentially the same for $H_{2n+1}(K)$.

Comment: Dear Alain: I agree with you and thanks

Comment: @YemonChoi: Thanks. In fact, I would like to verify the reduced group C*-algebra of the Jacobi group satisfies the Kunneth formula in the sense of Schochet. We can for instance prove that it belongs to the bootstrap class, which contains all type I algebras.